# How to have two inline divs on one line but make on expand responsively and push all the other content down

Tags: html, css

I want repeated rows of 2 divs.  In each row one div will contain an image and the second will contain a description.  I want each pair of divs to remain on the same line and aligned at the top always.  But as the screen is shrunk, the second div will expand vertically to accomodate the text with less width.  As this happens I would like all other rows of div-pairs to get pushed down so they remain aligned at the top also.

It seems so simple but I cant do it, an explanation of what I am missing and a solution would be fantastic.

Here's my code so far:

CSS:

```
<style>
.container{  
width: auto;
height: auto;
border: solid 1px blueviolet;  
}

.photo-box{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width:150px;
height:150px;
border:solid 1px red;
}

.details-box{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width:auto;
height:auto;
min-height:150px;
min-width: 100px; 
border:solid 1px black; 
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="photo-box"></div>
        <div class="details-box">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Earum veritatis suscipit beatae sed aut illum similique 
            porro a molestias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Suscipit cupiditate voluptatum aspernatur ad cum voluptates dolorum 
            quo reprehenderit ut fugiat? Praesentium id maxime libero ut culpa
             neque dignissimos nulla dolorem.
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
             Earum veritatis suscipit beatae sed aut illum similique 
             porro a molestias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
             Suscipit cupiditate voluptatum aspernatur ad cum voluptates dolorum 
             quo reprehenderit ut fugiat? Praesentium id maxime libero ut culpa
              neque dignissimos nulla dolorem.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="photo-box">
    </div>
    <div class="details-box">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Earum veritatis suscipit beatae sed aut illum similique 
            porro a molestias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Suscipit cupiditate voluptatum aspernatur ad cum voluptates dolorum 
            quo reprehenderit ut fugiat? Praesentium id maxime libero ut culpa
             neque dignissimos nulla dolorem.
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
             Earum veritatis suscipit beatae sed aut illum similique 
             porro a molestias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
             Suscipit cupiditate voluptatum aspernatur ad cum voluptates dolorum 
             quo reprehenderit ut fugiat? Praesentium id maxime libero ut culpa
              neque dignissimos nulla dolorem.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Try add a `<br>` tag

Comment: Change the inline-block

Comment: there is a br tag

Comment: Try margin, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top and margin-bottom

Comment: You may need to use JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try this by making your widths 49%, makeing them flex boxes and floating left the photo box.

```css
<style>
.container{  
border: solid 1px blueviolet;  
}

.photo-box{
display: flex;
vertical-align: top;
min-height:150px;
min-width: 100px; 
border:solid 1px red;
width: 49%;
float: left;
}

.details-box{
display: flex;
vertical-align: top;
min-height:150px;
min-width: 100px; 
border:solid 1px black; 
width: 49%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="photo-box"></div>
        <div class="details-box">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Earum veritatis suscipit beatae sed aut illum similique 
            porro a molestias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Suscipit cupiditate voluptatum aspernatur ad cum voluptates dolorum 
            quo reprehenderit ut fugiat? Praesentium id maxime libero ut culpa
             neque dignissimos nulla dolorem.
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
             Earum veritatis suscipit beatae sed aut illum similique 
             porro a molestias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
             Suscipit cupiditate voluptatum aspernatur ad cum voluptates dolorum 
             quo reprehenderit ut fugiat? Praesentium id maxime libero ut culpa
              neque dignissimos nulla dolorem.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="photo-box">
    </div>
    <div class="details-box">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Earum veritatis suscipit beatae sed aut illum similique 
            porro a molestias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Suscipit cupiditate voluptatum aspernatur ad cum voluptates dolorum 
            quo reprehenderit ut fugiat? Praesentium id maxime libero ut culpa
             neque dignissimos nulla dolorem.
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
             Earum veritatis suscipit beatae sed aut illum similique 
             porro a molestias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
             Suscipit cupiditate voluptatum aspernatur ad cum voluptates dolorum 
             quo reprehenderit ut fugiat? Praesentium id maxime libero ut culpa
              neque dignissimos nulla dolorem.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: This makes the photo box and details box appear on top of each other, i want them side by side, but otherwise the responsive behavior seems to work as i want it to

Comment: if add flex container to the container it starts to work.